# Chosing specific dates/hours from an array

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that has 3months of data or so..Its a 952x1 matrix with the elements in the following format(3 hourly )

```
   Aug-05-2015 03:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 06:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 09:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 12:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 15:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 18:00:00
   Aug-05-2015 21:00:00
   Aug-06-2015 00:00:00
   Aug-06-2015 03:00:00
   Aug-06-2015 06:00:00
```

I would want to choose say only day timings/ only night or say for august month alone. How do i do that.

Further to my question, if I have a group of .wav files and Im trying to pick only month wise or do daily psd averages etc or chose files belonging to a month how to go about? The following are first 10 .wav files in a .txt file that are read into matlab code-

```
AMAR168.1.20150823T200235Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T201040Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T201845Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T202650Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T203455Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T204300Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T205105Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T205910Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T210715Z.wav
```

yyyymmddTHHMMSSZ.wav is part of the format to get sense of some parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: What **exactly** is the format of the array? Are they time numbers? Strings? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are these datetimes?  If so, you can use logical indexing here if you make use of some of the datetime functions.  To get the times in August:

```
t = datetime(2015, 8, 1, 3, 0, 0) + hours(3:3:3000)';
t(month(t) == 8)  % Times in August
```

To get the times that are during the day or night:

```
t(hour(t) < 12)   % Day times
t(hour(t) >= 12)  % Night times
```

Comment: And of course, you can combine these.  Morning times in August:
    t((month(t) == 8) & (hour(t) < 12))

Comment: yes the class is datetime for this matrix. thanks a ton